# How to reference embedded dll from single Costura Fody dll

Tags: c#, dll, fody-costura

I installed Costura Fody via Nuget and embedded the appropriate dll's into one single dll. From the output window I can see that this is a success

[image]

I reference the created dll in the project I want to use it

[image]

and remove the references to the individual dll's that is now embedded. How do I access the namespaces of the embedded dll's? The only namespace available is Costura, so I can do a

```
using Costura;
```

but all my types are now unrecognised. Is thre something else that I have to do?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the using references as per normal. You should not remove namespace references to the libraries embedded by Costura.

Comment: I'm including the using references as per normal but the namespace are not recognized.